# centering a google maps iframe

Tags: html, css, positioning, center

Hi im not really familiar with CSS, however i need a google maps to be centered on my page, my current code dont work the way i want it. :S

here is my html

```
<div class="maps">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zZVPDX7DZETc.kFjAmXvee3Zc" width="512" height="384"></iframe>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```
.maps {
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
```

what am i doing wrong? i also tried with margin-right/left: auto; that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are typically two ways of centring an element, if it is `display:block` then you can `margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;` as long as it has a `width` set. If it is `display:inline` then you can use `text-align:center` on its parent

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
.maps {
    width: 512px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hcwy81oj/

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to add a div. You can just give it a class inside.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zZVPDX7DZETc.kFjAmXvee3Zc" width="512" height="384" class="map"></iframe>
```

If that can help anyone ...

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is within an element with a fixed width, with google defaults on the iframe embed code:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=YourMap" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0; margin:0 auto;" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```